# How to easily toggle to and from High Performance power mode in Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, power-management

Windows 7 and 8 have three default "power modes", regarding how much the prioritise speed vs conserving energy: "Power saver", "Balanced", and "High Performance".

On a portable machine with a battery you can easily switch between "Power saver" and "Balanced" with this from the system tray ([source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/power-plans-faq#1TC=windows-8)):

[image]

Is there any way to toggle to and from High Performance?

Answer (score 1):

That popup window isn't actually fixed to "Balanced" and "Power saver", it shows the two most recently used modes, with those two as defaults.

So if you hit "More power options" and choose High Performance, which by default is hidden under "Show additional plans"...

[image]

...it then appears in the system tray popup:

[image]

I don't think there's any way to toggle between all three plans at once.

Comment: "it shows the two most recently used modes" - No it does not. It **always** shows Balanced, even when you've switched from High performance to Power saving hundreds of times, and haven't used Balanced for years. I'd like an answer to the OP's question